# hash function return not hexa value

Tags: php, hash, benchmarking, sha

I'm just trying some benchmark on hash functions and their speed and in one case I encoutred strange issue. Code is easy, i create hash from random number, then another hash from random and the i put this together with few serverand local values and take how much execution take.

I know that it's crazy code, nut it's just for benchmark and question is out of my curiosity:

CODE:

```
$salt1 = hash( 'sha1', uniqid( mt_rand( 1, mt_getrandmax() ), true ) );
$token1 = hash( 'sha1', uniqid( mt_rand( 1, mt_getrandmax() ), true ) );
$token2 = hash( 'sha1', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] . $salt1 . $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] . $token1 . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] , true  );
```

After this code is finished I end up with time and values salt1, token1 and token2. I was not looking at values, but just from luck i encoutred this values:

```
$salt1 = e93edda7d1810efb661fe0b4eb85c92256516302
$token1 = ca43d77821ddc90b6b0bfebe1a20f1985547dbeb
$token2 = >)c³‡Ìq£Vé‘Æä¯ËÊü*
```

As you cen see, in token2 there is no hexa value. How is it possible if this function should return hexa values?

Comment: Remove the `true` at the end. Having the `true` as you can see from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) means that the output value is raw binary format.

Comment: Och, i am idiot i coppied that by mistake from uniqid :D thanks, make it answer so i can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `true` at the end. Having this boolean parameter set to `true` as you can see from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) means that the output value is in raw binary format